# How to setup conditional highlight between two cells:

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Looking to understand how to highlight one cell in one column based on what a cell in a neighbor column says.

Column H, in my spreadsheet, displays a differing number of required hours to graduate and Column G displays how many hours have been completed. I need to highlight each cell in G that exceeds the designated number in the neighboring H cell. (Example screenshot attached).

In the example, notice the requirement (2nd column: H) is 600, 2000, 720 or 1040 and that cell 1, 2, 4 surpass, but 3 and 5 do not. I need 1, 2, 4 to highlight but not the other two... or to highlight those that exceed in one color and those that don't in another.

How do I set it up so that my spreadsheet identifies the individual Requirement Number in H as the "Greater Than" marker?

I have tried to set up a "Greater Than" conditional format, but this requires me to enter a specific number...
I have also tried a "Use a Formula" conditional format: =$G:$G>$H:$H, but this causes the entire row to highlight, regardless of what's entered...
I've tried "Use a Formula" conditional format: =$G$2>$H$2, but it only works for the one specific cell and do not know how to then apply the same formula to all cells in these columns without having to do it one-by-one.

Will be so grateful for an assist on this!

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

- Select the values to compare : `A2:A6`
- On the Home pane of the ribbon, click *Conditional Formatting > New Rule...*
- Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter the formula `=A2>B2`
- Click `Format...` and specify the desired formatting
- Click OK twice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When following this method (A2>B2), all lower rows are going to be based off of B2, are they not? How would I go about making A15 compare to B15 and not B2 without having to format line-by-line?

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, Excel adjusts the row numbers for the following rows.